# Powershell Parameter Passing

Tags: powershell-2.0

This seems so trivial, but I can't figure out why the parameters I'm passing into a .ps1 script from the command pane aren't getting captured correctly as shown in this image below. String parameters are just empty, numbers are 0 which tells me I've overlooked something basic! This is with Powershell v2.

[image: Powershell ISE]

Comment: Your 2nd invocation is without a path, implying that `test.ps1` is executed from somewhere in your `$env:PATH` rather than from the current directory. Try `.\test.ps1 -p1 21` from the directory in which the script is located (or use the full path, as in the 1st invocation).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mklement0.
It was, in fact, a path issue within the ISE

[image]